# codeigniter custom library undefine property error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a codeigniter custom library(My_payment_gate_way_init) for my payment gateway.. but when i use my custom library function , controller(Billing) not passing parameters into the library it shows

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Billing::$My_payment_gate_way_init

Filename: controllers/Billing.php

Line Number: 576
```

that error occurs when i use

**Controller**

```
    public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('My_payment_gate_way_init');
    }

function saveord(){
$ammount = $this->totlCost * 100;
$this->My_payment_gate_way_init->setTransactionAmountforPay($ammount);
}
```

**library**

```
class My_payment_gate_way_init
{

    private $clientConfig;
    private $initRequest;
    private $transactionAmount;
    private $redirect;
    private $initResponse;
    private $client;
    private $CI;
    function __construct()
    {
 $this->setTransactionAmountforPay();
}

  function setTransactionAmountforPay($ammount=200){
        // sets transaction-amounts details (all amounts are in cents)
        $this->transactionAmount = new TransactionAmount();
        $this->transactionAmount->setTotalAmount(0);
        $this->transactionAmount->setServiceFeeAmount(0);
        $this->transactionAmount->setPaymentAmount($ammount);
        $this->transactionAmount->setCurrency("LKR");
        $this->initRequest->setTransactionAmount($this->transactionAmount);
    }
```

also it shows this error at bottom

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setTransactionAmountforPay() on
>   null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\debug_online\application\controllers\Billing.php on
>   line 576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an object first before calling the function.

```
$this->My_payment_gate_way_init = new My_payment_gate_way_init();
$this->My_payment_gate_way_init->setTransactionAmountforPay($ammount);
```

Comment: YES... Thanx bro. you save my life.